# Create a function to copy n char like strcpy in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void nhap(char* &scr, int *n)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Input the string length:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", n);
    } while (n < 0);

    scr = (char*)malloc(*n * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%c", (scr + i));
    }
}

void xuat(char* scr, int n)
{
    printf("\nThe content of string: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", *(scr + i));
    }
}

char* StringNCopy(char* dest, char* scr, int n)
{
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    dest = (char*)realloc(dest, n * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = *(scr + n); j > 0; j--)
        {
            *(dest + i) = *(scr + j);
        }
    }
    *(dest + n) = '\0';
    return dest;
}


void main()
{

    char *a;
    char *b=NULL;
    int n;
    nhap(a, &n);
    xuat(a, n);
    StringNCopy(b, a, 4);
    printf("%s", *b);
    free(a);
}
```

Excuse me, I have a problem, I want to create a function likes strcpy but there is some errors I can't fix by myself. I think it will copy n elements from char* scr to char* dest, but when I run my code, it crashed. Can you help me to fix the code and explain to me. I'm very thankful.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the strncpy() function of string.h header?

Comment: `{ memcpy(dest,src,n); dest[n] = 0; }`

Comment: @ryyker yeah, I used malloc for char* scr

Comment: @hecate it's my exercise, and I have to create a new one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing a string copy function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695992/implementing-a-string-copy-function-in-c)

Comment: @ryyker where is your comments and your code, did you delete it away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loops should be in this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(dest + i) = *(scr + i);
    }
```

You dont need nested for loops for this, because you just need to traverse the array once and copy the values.

Corrected program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void nhap(char* &scr, int *n)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Input the string length:\n");
        scanf("%d", n);
    } while (n < 0);

    scr = (char*)malloc((*n+1) * sizeof(char));    //allocated size should be n+1
    fflush(stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", (scr+i ));
    }

}

void xuat(char* scr, int n)
{

    printf("\nThe content of string: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", *(scr + i));
    }
}

void StringNCopy(char* &dest, char* &scr, int n)     //no need to return the string aas you can pass it as reference
{

    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    dest = (char*)realloc(dest, (n+1) * sizeof(char));  //alloted size should be n+1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

            *(dest + i) = *(scr + i);         //no need of nested loops

    }
    *(dest + n) = '\0';

}


int main()
{

    char *a;
    char *b=NULL;
    int n;
    nhap(a, &n);

    xuat(a, n);
    StringNCopy(b, a, 4);

    printf("\n6%s", b);
    free(a);
}
```

Tested and working fine.
**Observe the errors mentioned in comments**

Comment: I tested. But you know, I want to copy n elements from the scr to the dest and the dest is empty. So I let the loop run from 0, but I can't do it with scr.

Comment: it crashed and out :D

Comment: Your code is very helpful. It helped me to find that I didn't try my best to solve it, but I can't change from char* to void :D, but now I can do it in char* function. Thank for your advice. Have a nice day <3

Comment: if the post was helpful, you can mark it as correct and upvote, to make it more helpful for other users